# Prestashop change styling of unavailbe product sizes

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am facing one problem of changing style of the unavailable sizes of product please help me to do so. my code is below

```
<ul id="color_to_pick_list" class="clearfix">
    {assign var="default_colorpicker" value=""}                                             
    {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
        {assign var='img_color_exists' value=file_exists($col_img_dir|cat:$id_attribute|cat:'.jpg')}
        <li{if $group.default == $id_attribute} class="selected"{/if}>
        <a href="{$link->getProductLink($product)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" id="color_{$id_attribute|intval}" name="{$colors.$id_attribute.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" class="color_pick{if ($group.default == $id_attribute)} selected{/if}" title="{$colors.$id_attribute.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
        {$group_attribute|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</a></li>
        {if ($group.default == $id_attribute)}
            {$default_colorpicker = $id_attribute}
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

So I want to show the the css line through for unavailable sizes of products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complicated because the stock is registered on Prestashop not on variations but on a whole, which will give him such a product size 38 red a different stock of a product size 38 green.

So with queries we can see variations not available, but that does not happen in two lines.

I recommend taking a module is all for it.

Regards,